# htaccess rewriterule windows/linux , domain to subpage

Tags: linux, windows, .htaccess, redirect

I have .htaccess rule defined:

```
# *** Presmerovania ***

RewriteEngine on

#www.domosskuchyne.sk
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www\.kuchynskelinkymoderne\.sk$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domosskuchyne.sk/bosch [r=301,nc]
```

On windows I get redirected to "http://www.domosskuchyne.sk/bosch" , but on linux server I am redirected only on main page "http://www.domosskuchyne.sk" not to subpage (/bosch) .

Is there something wrong with this rewrite rule ? .

Comment: yes, but only next redirects, just like one in example .
I tried 
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domosskuchyne.sk/$1 [r=301,nc] so when i went on "www.kuchynskelinkymoderne.sk/bosch" i got redirected to "http://www.domosskuchyne.sk/bosch" , but that is not what i wanted, i need to get redirected from "www.kuchynskelinkymoderne.sk" only .

Comment: Solved - Htaces is just fine, browsers  remember 301 redirects so redirects didnt changed till browser cache wasnt deleted, tnx for help .

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Htaccess is just fine, browsers remember 301 redirects so redirects didnt changed till browser cache wasnt deleted, tnx for help .